# Table border issue in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have issue when creating simple border
The border seems like bold in row 2 and last row, why this happened

[image]

Note: when back to w3school tutorial found the same issue I think it's like browser issue

///// Css code ///////

```
table{ border-collapse :collapse;}
Table, td { border: 1px solid black;
```

//// HTML code /////

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like it's a browser rendering issue. Could you provide the w3schools link?

Comment: change `Table, td { border: 1px solid black;` to `td,th { border: 1px solid black;`

Comment: W3school link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border-collapse

Comment: `thead` and `tbody` are missing

Comment: @mister Jojo
<th> not found in code , but I tried but not working

Comment: `<th>Firstname</th>`  `th` found in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code since it's pretty basic. You appended a screenshot - is it possible that your screen resolution is rather low?
**Try zooming in via "ctrl" + "+" and the lines will probably equal.**

Depending on screen resolution the thickness of each line is calucalted and may be for example 1.8 pixels - when rendering your computer has to either round up or down, which may result in the fact that some lines appear as 1px and others as 2px.

Comment: also same issue please check photo

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ExOjlxlCAVd8LEhQ7wnCiNV5XhxKA1uL/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is not at default zoom, and so the scaling is causing inconsistent line widths. Reset your browser zoom to 100% to fix the issue.

Comment: already 100% please check Link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uvhf2jFN6dEQZFV-Hz5uV0n2iHnBjSAf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm. Well the code you have in your question should not cause the inconsistency you are seeing. There must be either something off about your browser configuration or your markup / style sheets that is not seen here. Perhaps Windows has some scaling settings enabled?